# VMWare 4.0 - Adding LUN from Server2012R2 iSCSI Target - Capacity 2TB, Available 102.40GB?

Tags: windows-server-2012, vmware-esx, iscsi, vmware-vcenter, vhd

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 hosting some iSCSI targets/LUNs from a local raided JBOD via Virtual Disks.

I have created a thin provisioned 2TB VHDX in Windows and have added the target to VMWare. Upon selecting add storage in VMWare it shows the LUN as being 2TB but the available capacity is only 102GB before formatting.

Since I'm the kind of guy that likes to use more than 5% of storage made available I would greatly appreciate your input on what may be causing this and how to get around it.

Comment: Are you really using VMware vSphere 4.0?

Comment: Yeah, it sucks. New servers+ licences when me move to a bigger office in 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare KB 3371739:
[ESX/ESXi 3.x/4.x hosts do not support 2-terabyte LUNs (3371739)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=3371739)

So there is a 2TB - 512kb limit and as I went over that limit by 512kb it caused issues, so I had to create VDs that were each 2097151 MB in size rather than 2097152 MB.

From the KB article:

> Based on the standard, the largest valid LUN capacity support is (2^32)-1 sectors. This is the math involved in the calculation:
>
> (2^32) = 4294967296
>   4294967296 - 1 = 4294967295
>
> If you take the above number and multiply it by 512 bytes per sector, you get the size limitation in bytes:
>
> 4294967295 x 512 = 2199023255040
>
> The limit of 2TB translates to:
>
> 4294967295 sectors
>      2199023255040 bytes